# Including header, menu, and footer in controllers

Tags: php, controller, include, footer

I'm creating my own primitive MVC (or MVP as some may call it) framework, and I would like to know a best practice way of including a header, footer and anything else in my controllers.

Currently I'm doing it like the following at the end of **every** controller:

```
class Index extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $hData = array(
            'title'       => 'Home',
            'stylesheets' => array(
                'style1.css',
                'style2.css'
            ),
            'javascripts' => array(
                'script1.js',
                'script2.js'
            )
        );

        $cData = array(
            'heading' => 'My first PHP application',
            'message' => 'Hello, world!'
        );

        //HTML Output
        $header  = new View('/views/header.php');
        $html    = $header->fetch($hData);

        $menu    = new View('/views/menu.php');
        $html   .= $header->fetch();

        $content = new View('/views/index.php');
        $html   .= $content->fetch($cData);

        $footer  = new View('/views/footer.php');
        $html   .= $footer->fetch();

        echo $html;
    }
}
```

Am I doing it correctly or is there a better way of doing it? If so, I would highly appreciate an example.

Comment: imo, A 'controller' is more like a 'manager'. It asks others to 'show stuff with proper headers and footers' rather than does it itself. It needs to know which 'view' needs to be called in which circumstances. The 'view' and the 'model' decide the contents.

Comment: I think it's hard to answer this question without a project specification. If you are building an application for 1.000.000 users you will have other requirements then when you are building an application for 100 users. From my experience I can tell that you need a far more sophisticated framework if you are building a huge application. Besides the framework architecture question I want to give you the advice to take a look at SPAs. IMO this is the future. AngularJS is a nice framework to start with. If you want to write your own SPA framework be sure you have enough knowledge of JS(mem leaks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, building MVC framework on your own, will force you to accept some compromises. But here is what I think:

1. You should have some templating engine (ideally, potentially replaceable). It can be either just PHP, or some already existing (Twig, Smarty)
2. Controllers should only know about particular view that would be rendered by the templating engine. As such, views should probably be available by names rather than by concrete paths to the template files.
3. Templating engine should know how to resolve the template name to the real template files.
4. Templating engine should be able to accept variables for the template, that can be passed to it from the controller.
5. Including header, footer, etc., should be considered either by your templating engine or within your templates, but not within your controller. For example, your code may support AJAX-calls showing some partial inner-html. In this case, the name for the template can be the same, but according to some var, passed from the controller, the templating engine (or the template itself) can show header and footer for normal requests and omit them for ajax requests.
6. And definitely, it's not controller's task to define in a hard-coded way, which css files to load in the template. However, there *may* be some system setting that could be read within the controller and then passed to the template as a variable.

2 and 3 can be optional, if you don't need extra flexibility or you are pretty sure that you won't need to switch to Smarty or Twig later.

Answer (score 1):

MVC is designed specifically to separate functions.

**Model** - Think of this as your application layer. When you are designing your model it is the application itself. What content will you need? This typically is returned in raw form. Arrays, objects, JSon, etc.

**View** - The view is how you serve data. PHP makes a great templating engine, but there are others, like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net) or [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/), that are based on PHP and are designed exclusively for templates. Look them up, see what you think. I personally use Smarty and am looking at Symfony (an MVC framework that uses Twig for views) for a potential future project. But many say PHP alone works just fine. There are definitely pros and cons to each.

**Controller** - Controllers tell the program what to do and where to go. This is your business logic layer. Your Front Controller sits in between your Model and your View in order to put the right content into the right places.

Therefore, when thinking about headers and footers, consider where they belong. In the end because it is a question of templating and images it is probably best suited in a View.

## Edit: An Example of a View

If you choose to use PHP as your template, you can go from very basic (hard to scale) all the way up to a highly dynamic object oriented template engine from scratch. Depending on the scope of your project, I will once again highly recommend that you at least *look* at Smarty or Twig as an option.

**Simple Template: User Profile**
Templates can be as simple as this:

```
<?php include("header.html.php");
 /*I am using .html because you can also create .xml views.
      The beauty of MVC is you can create multiple views with 
      the same model, just having your controller direct 
      to the correct view. */ ?>
<!-- Your content here -->
    <div id="userPicture"><img src="<?php echo $userPictureLocation; ?>"></div>
    <div id="userDetails">
        <div id="userName">
            <span class="key">Name:</span>
            <span class="value"><?php echo $userNameValue; ?></span>
        </div>
        <div id="userBio">
            <span class="key">Bio:</span>
            <span class="value"><?php echo $userBioValue; ?></span>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- End Content -->
<?php include ("footer.html.php"); ?>
```

Using this very simple and hard-to-maintain template system, you can simply use `include $file;` in your Front Controller.

If you want to create an object oriented view and not use a templating engine like Smarty or Twig, then you'll be looking to create your own object classes. You can probably take a look at the functionality of Smarty and/or Twig to get an idea of what would be required. It is reinventing the wheel, but reinventing the wheel is a great learning tool. A very simple initial thing you could do, however, is add a Template class that had the functions `setValue()`, `getValue()`, and `load()`. `load()` and `setValue()` could be used in your template, and `getValue()` can be used in your template.

```
class template {
    private $values;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->values = array();
    }

    public function setValue($key, $value) {
        $this->values[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function getValue($key) {
        return $this->values[$key];
    }

    public function load($file) {
        //The APPLOCATION constant below would be under a configuration
        //file define('APPLOCATION','/var/www/html/'); or whatever your app location
        //is. A Registry Class is probably a better bet for a large application and is
        //the best practices way to do it.
        include APPLOCATION . "template/{$file}";
    }
}
```

This class is very lightweight but also can be added to. It prevents some of the more egregious replication and can be extended with limited effort.

So once again, the template we looked at before, this time with the Template object.

```
<?php 
//In this example I am assuming you declared a new Template 
//in your Controller and assigned it the value of $template.
$template->load("header.html.php");
?>
<!-- Your content here -->
    <div id="userPicture"><img src="<?php echo $template->getValue('userPictureLocation'); ?>"></div>
    <div id="userDetails">
        <div id="userName">
            <span class="key">Name:</span>
            <span class="value"><?php echo $template->value('userNameValue'); ?></span>
        </div>
        <div id="userBio">
            <span class="key">Bio:</span>
            <span class="value"><?php echo $template->value('userBioValue'); ?></span>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- End Content -->
<?php $template->load("footer.html.php"); ?>
```

Comment: Could you maybe provide an example of the view described in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a printView method that takes your two params and wraps this away? If you really wanted to there's no reason you need to specify the scripts if they're not going to change. Something like:

```
class Controller {

    // Protected makes it visible to children, but not to callers
    protected function printHTML($bodyPage, $bodyData = array(), $altHeaders = array()){
        $defaultHeaders = array(
            'title'       => 'Home',
            'stylesheets' => array(
                'style1.css',
                'style2.css'
            ),
            'javascripts' => array(
                'script1.js',
                'script2.js'
            )
        );
        $trueHeaders = array_merge_recursive($defaultHeaders, $altHeaders);

        $header  = new View('/views/header.php');
        $html    = $header->fetch($trueHeaders);

        $menu    = new View('/views/menu.php');
        $html   .= $header->fetch();

        $content = new View($bodyPage);
        $html   .= $content->fetch($bodyData);

        $footer  = new View('/views/footer.php');
        $html   .= $footer->fetch();

        echo $html;
   }
}

class Index extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->printHTML(
            '/views/index.php',
            array(
                'heading' => 'My first PHP application',
                'message' => 'Hello, world!'
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'My Index Page',
                'stylesheets' => array(
                    'style3.css'// Will use styles 1, 2 and 3 because we merge the array recursively.
                )
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: The scripts and style sheets can be different for every controller.

Comment: @KidDiamond that is why you only include the constant stuff(jquery and a basic layout or something), each page can then define it's own additions to the list like it can override the title.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder called layout and place a file named Header and a file named footer and put all tags until your content div and then require the view file from the `View.php` after the header.php then put your footer.php and require after the file and close all the tags. That's how I do it.